# Scroll JavaScript em div e pegar título

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Vamos ao problema:

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<span id="título">teste1</span>
<div id="div_scroll">
  <div id="dv1">teste1</div>
  <div id="dv2">teste2</div>
  <div id="dv3">teste3</div>
  <div id="dv4">teste4</div>
...
</div>
```

Supondo que tenha muitas divs teste ali dentro e a div id "div_scroll" e que a div id 'dv1' seja o topo. Gostaria de quando descer ou rodar o scroll da div id "div_scroll" e quando cada div id "dv?" chegar ao topo, jogar o texto dentro dela para o spam id título. Pesquisei e achei alguns plugins que fazem isso. Porém acredito que tenha algum meio mais simples para fazer isso.

Comment: Ou você usa um plugin ou você escreve ele. Se já tem um plugin pequeno pra isso, mais rápido usa-lo do que reinventar a roda.

Comment: Se você não sabe exatamente como fazer, melhor usar o plugin que já está pronto

Comment: O plugin é grande. Imagino que se faça esse trabalho com menos código.  Se não ter como fazer isso, sim, usarei o plugin... Obrigado

Comment: @lfabra  
Você procura uma solução com JavaScript puro ou está usando jQuery ou similares.

Comment: É indiferente pra mim. Mas estou montando um plugin jquery, e se não precisar de outro plugin para isso, será perfeito.

Comment: @Ifabra - Uma solução com JavaScript puro em:   https://jsfiddle.net/maujor/p74avfwx/

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo utilizando jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // Escuta o movimento do scrool.
  $('#div_scroll').scroll(function() {
    // Obtem a posição do elemento div_scroll na tela.
    var divScrollPosition = $('#div_scroll').position();

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollCheck'));

    // Função executada ao concluir o movimento de scrool.
    $.data(this, 'scrollCheck', setTimeout(function() {

      // Pecorre todas as sub divs e verifica qual a sua posição.
      $('#div_scroll div').each(function() {
        var divPosition = $(this).position();

        /* (Posição do elemento div_scroll - (Posição da div + 1)) + Altura da div.
           + 1: Como a div tem um borda de 1px é somado mais 1 para discontar essa borda.
           altura da div: Utilizado para exibir o título da div enquanto a mesma estiver visível */
        var position = (divPosition.top - (divScrollPosition.top + 1)) + $(this).height();

        // Se posição maior que zero indica que a mesma ainda está visível.
        if (position > 0) {
          $('#titulo').text($(this).text());
          return false;
        }
      });
      
    }, 250));
  });
});
```

```css
#div_scroll {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="titulo">teste1</span>
<div id="div_scroll">
  <div id="dv1">teste1</div>
  <div id="dv2">teste2</div>
  <div id="dv3">teste3</div>
  <div id="dv4">teste4</div>
  <div id="dv5">teste5</div>
  <div id="dv6">teste6</div>
  <div id="dv7">teste7</div>
  <div id="dv8">teste8</div>
  <div id="dv9">teste9</div>
  <div id="dv10">teste10</div>
  <div id="dv11">teste11</div>
  <div id="dv12">teste12</div>
</div>
```

Referência sobre scrollstop: http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-check-if-users-stop-scrolling

Comment: Para não engessar o código a uma borda de 1px sugiro armazenar a espessura da borda superior em uma variável e usar a variável em lugar de 1px.  
`var borderTopWidth = $('#div_scroll').css("borderTopWidth");`

Comment: Uma solução com JavaScript puro em: https://jsfiddle.net/maujor/p74avfwx